# ADMX Templates Missing - But not really

Tags: group-policy

This is driving me crazy...

I have a bunch of ADMX templates which I would like to make use off in my domain.  I have installed them locally to C:\Windows\PolicyDefiniations (and placed the corresponding ADML files in a en-US subfolder.

To say I created would be wrong, since the domain was built a long time ago by someone else, but there is a folder present for a central store, namely - \domainname\sysvol\domainname\PolicyDefiniations (and the language subfolder).

These folders are identical in contents, confirmed by a folder comparison tool.

If I open gpedit.msc on the Domain Controller, it sees all the ADMX files and reads them as I would expect them to, however, if I open gpmc.msc and expand a new (or existing) Group Policy Object then I don't see the same options and fairly obvious templates which have their own 'folder', such as FSLogix are completely missing, but present if I use gpedit.msc

If I open the gpmc.msc console, I can see that it says it's looking for the templates in the central store, but something isn't right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your central store is created under the wrong directory, it should be:

`\\domain.name\SYSVOL\domain.name\policies\PolicyDefinitions` (you forgot "policies", thus gpmc will not be able to find the administrative templates)

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Thanks.